# Cannot invoke 'stringFromDate' with an argument list of type '(NSData)'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I fix this issue?

in line num 5

it show me this error "cannot invoke 'stringFromDate' error in swift
"

> ```
>  let today = NSData()
>
>  let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
>
>  formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
>
>  var newTask =
>  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Tasks",
>  inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
>
>  newTask.setValue(formatter.stringFromDate(today), forKey: "taskDate")
> ```

Comment: typo?  Did you mean `let today = NSDate()` instead of `NSData()`?

Comment: Change let today = NSData() to let today = NSDate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in word NSDate. Change this line of code:

```
let today = NSData()
```

to this:

```
let today = NSDate()
```